# Get null fields after deserialization java JSON

Tags: java, null, json-deserialization, rest-assured, dto

I assume a problen in class structure. But I do not see where. Here is a code. I'm gonna use only some values from JSON. If you need some other code part just let me know. Maily I think I get objest (user) wuth null values here:

```
User userDTOGetOne = userRequester.getUser
  (
    token,
    new HashMap<String, Object>() {{ put("Uuid", userResponseDTO.getUserUuid()); }}
   )
   .getBody()
   .as(User.class);
```

I suppose here is a problem .as(User.class) with class structure. I have compared them not once and I can not find a problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Here is a link to the code   https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OrHlWiiT4khiwqdT-t7QlYmOyT52NsTE?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you show the error that you got?

Comment: Problem is not solver to end, next heplped. Type to Integer change in : private Integer HighSchoolUuid;

Comment: And this variable also is modified to:  private HashMap<String, CustomFieldDTO> UserCustomFields;

Comment: I used handmade check to figure out where problems are. It was helpful: new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(
                    new User()
                            .set .......

Comment: this set was the most interesring: .setUserCustomFields(
                                    new HashMap<String, CustomFieldDTO>() {{

Comment: put(
                                                    "bb854ba1-8ef7-4cfb-9fe7-8c6d9a0551b2",
                                                    new CustomFieldDTO()
                                                            .setIsDefault(false)
                                                            .setSerializedValue(SerializedValue1)
                                            );

Comment: Please, edit your question to people know what your problem is, don't spam comment. Thanks

Comment: lucasnguyen17, the error in in the mistake.txt. The link to it you have in the first comment

Comment: also there is interesting thing. I've made seriliazation by hand - it works. But auto serialization does not work, I get nulls. The current code will be in NewTestCode.txt with the same link in a moment

Comment: Could you provide log request and response for this test, to make sure get you correct response before deserialization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found out your problems.

1.`@JsonRootName("User")` in `User` class doesn't work, I have to create a separate `UserDTo` class.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class UserDTO {
    @JsonProperty("User")
    private User user;
}
```

2.In class `User`

```
private HashMap<String, HashMap<String, CustomFieldDTO> > UserCustomFields;
```

should be

```
private Map<String, CustomFieldDTO> UserCustomFields;
```

3.In class `CustomFieldDTO`

```
private HashMap<String, CustomFieldVariableDTO> WebAdmin;
private HashMap<String, CustomFieldVariableDTO> Client;
```

should be

```
private CustomFieldVariableDTO WebAdmin;
private CustomFieldVariableDTO Client;
```

---

I make a simple test

```
UserDTO user = res.as(UserDTO.class);
System.out.println(user);

UserDTO(user=User(Uuid=b5ee1186-7355-4810-a422-c427c1ae420c, 
Username=golden_snich_testt, Email=golsnich4599@gmail.com, FirstName=Bob, 
LastName=Sigal, Birthdate=1995-01-07T00:00:00Z, Phone=+12698741258, 
Notes=null, Locked=false, PostPayLimit=10.0, HighSchoolUuid=null, 
IsVerifiedHighSchoolUser=false, UserCustomFields={9cebfaaa-ca66-4bbd-baa3- 
557b0645c293=CustomFieldDTO(FieldUuid=null, FieldType=String, 
FieldName=null, WebAdmin=CustomFieldVariableDTO(Status=0, 
AllowChangeStatus=false), Client=CustomFieldVariableDTO(Status=0, 
AllowChangeStatus=false), IsDefault=false, 
SerializedValue=Nickyfieldname213241), bb854ba1-8ef7-4cfb-9fe7- 
8c6d9a0551b2=CustomFieldDTO(FieldUuid=null, FieldType=String, 
FieldName=null, WebAdmin=CustomFieldVariableDTO(Status=0, 
AllowChangeStatus=false), Client=CustomFieldVariableDTO(Status=0, 
AllowChangeStatus=false), IsDefault=false, 
SerializedValue=Nickyfieldname2)}))
```

Comment: Thank you. Is is workable. Some variable type changes I have figured out by myself. I checked only fields which I am in a need currently. And I have at the moment only one problematic field Notes. Firstly, could you be so pleased to explain why we needed additional DTO around User to make it workable, I thought is was okey. Secondly, about field Notes. I pass some value. Auto serialization returns me null. Serialization made by hand returns value. But I've noticed interesting thing in terminal. We get JSON structure of our user in terminal, this is our response, and we get there null in Notes

Comment: I mean that by default we get there null as response on our request. It is strange. I pass value. But I suppose it is suck logic mde by programmers

Comment: "User": {
        "Uuid": "9f12b830-263c-4488-ba8b-915954eea2a8",
        "Username": "golden_snich_testt",
        "Email": "golsnich4599@gmail.com",
        "FirstName": "Bob",
        "LastName": "Sigal",
        "CenterUuid": "4caf8e5a-e233-4206-8b73-e6e302b929ec",
        "Birthdate": "1995-01-07T00:00:00Z",
        "TimeRemaining": 0,
        "AccountStatus": "open",
        "StudentId": null,
        "Phone": "+12698741258",
        "LastSeen": null,
        "Deleted": false,
        "Notes": null   This is a part of JSON from terminal after execution of my test

Comment: Because only one assert have not passed  Failures: 
[ERROR]   PostCreateUserApiTest.createUserSuccessfullyWithTestGroupAndDTOComparison:357 Multiple Failures (1 failure)
        Notes do not Match ==> expected: <Go on> but was: <null>

Comment: I added two png files - photos from the terminal about value of Notes field to the shared folder - the link is the same - you can find the link in the vety first comment

Comment: How have you figured out that annotation does not work? It was your thoughts, experience of solving such problems? Thank you

Comment: First, I sometimes use this for serialization not deserialization, it's strange for me. Second, when I turn it off, I see errors in other places (wrong types).

Comment: I have to admit that your code so verbose and ugly.(1) You should create smaller test and use compare object instead of compare each field (time-consuming). (2) Create object and fill data by using setters, you made very long Map in Map, it's so hard to follow, not good for maintainance.